# Align input field in center vertically/horizontally in an overlay

Tags: html, css

I need to show search field as an overlay when user clicks on the search icon. In my case overlay is working but search input field is showing in middle vertically.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbMw3/634/)

```
<a href="#overlay" id="open-overlay">Search</a>

<div id="overlay"> <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
    <div class="s-wrapper"><input value="" placeholder="Search"/></div>
</div>
```

This overlay is based on pure css solution as i cant use script based overlay in this case.

Comment: You want to place the input in the vertical center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following works for you:

```
.s-wrapper{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbMw3/635/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this page](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).

```
.s-wrapper{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

CSS,

```
.s-wrapper{
  height: 500px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vbMw3/640/)